# Meaning of 'ends meet'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of **ends meet** in this context

> Hi,
>
> This email is to inform you that your application has been rejected.
>   As the Test scores were not enough. However, we wish you all success
>   in all your future endeavors.
>
> If ends meet we would look forward to working with you in the near
>   future.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I regard that as nonstandard usage, and I am reminded of the phrase "making ends meet." That phrase seems to be unrelated here. The last sentence seems to be saying something about inviting the applicant to try again, but "ends meet" isn't functional English, unless it's a dialectical thing.

Raising further suspicion, "As the Test..." is a fragment, so the English level of the composer of the message probably indicates he isn't too sure about what he's doing either.

Comment: ***All*** *success in **all** your future endeavours* is also awkward.

Comment: I am thinking that sender wants to say that, If we come across in future than can work with you but as of now no chance. Am I right?

Comment: Something like that.